# Blender game Engine collision sensor, property value

Tags: logic-bricks

my problem is that i have 3 platforms that react to a specific object.
If the object hits the platform i want to change the property value to 1, so that my game knows theres the object on the platform.
Sadly it seems like the property value doesnt count up.

my blender version is 2.79a

Greetings
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, i had to activate the TRUE level triggering, now it works